# Loop over bean array In JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Hey guys I have a bean that comes back and one of the properties in the bean is an array of another bean.

I can get my other properties out fine and display on the jsp while looping, but I need to get the contents of my array out.  I know im doing it wrong and forgot what the syntax is for something like that.

Baaically I need `role.id` in the last column.  This is what I got:

JSP:

```
   <table class="data_table">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test='${empty attachList}'>
           <tr>
              <td>No Attachments</td>
           </tr>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <tr>
                <th>Remove Attachment</th>
                <th>File Name</th>
                <th>File Type</th>
                <th>File Size (bytes)</th>
                <th>File Attached By</th>
                <th>Date/Time File Attached</th>
                <th>Roles</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="item" items="${attachList}" varStatus="loopCount">
                <tr>

                    <td class="button">
                    <rbac:check operation="<%=Operation.DELETE%>">
                        <button type="button"  onclick="javascript:delete_prompt(${item.id});">Delete</button>
                    </rbac:check>
                        </td>
                    <td><a href="show.view_hotpart_attachment?id=${item.id}">${item.fileName}</a></td>
                    <td>${item.fileType}</td>
                    <td><fmt:formatNumber value="${item.fileSize}" /></td>
                    <td>${item.auditable.createdBy.lastName}, ${item.auditable.createdBy.firstName}</td>
                    <td><fmt:formatDate value="${item.auditable.createdDate}" pattern="${date_time_pattern}" /></td>
                    <td>${item.roles}</td>

                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
    </table>
```

Bean:

Bean class im looping over in `items="${attachList}"`

```
private long id;
private String fileName;
private String fileType;
private int fileSize;
private Role[] roles;
private AuditableBean auditable;

/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public AttachmentShortBean()
{
}

public long getId() { return id; }

public String getFileName() { return fileName; }

public String getFileType() { return fileType; }

public int getFileSize() { return fileSize; }

public Role[] getRoles() { return roles; }

public AuditableBean getAuditable() { return auditable; }
```

Role is another bean and its getters are `getName()` and `getId()`

I need to diaply the array of id's in the last column, but Im just getting a memory location...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to loop over your roles as well

```
<c:forEach items = "${item.roles}" var = "role">
   <c:out value = "${role.id}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Another possibility is

```
<c:out value = "${item.roles[0].id}"/>
```

If you're only looking for the first role.